# Do node.js forked processes share any memory via copy-on-write?

Tags: node.js, fork, copy-on-write

In (some?) Unix systems when you `fork` a process the new process will share memory with its predecessor. The memory will be shared as long as it's unchaged. This is called cow, copy-on-write.

I wonder if Node.js process forking has any technical benefits from cow. If it does then what do Node.js processes share exactly?

Comment: I realise this isn't directly related but maybe has some useful information? If not ignore me.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12902

Comment: @ste2425 That's cow for files. I was talking about RAM. Closly related technology.

Comment: @freakish https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options This link says it's not the case for variables in your js code. However it's not clear if runtime itself or libs may be cowed.

Comment: @Gherman Right, that's because nodejs' "fork" is not fork at all. I find it hilarious that they've named it like that. https://dev.to/pi0/nodejs-fork-is-not-what-you-think-of-37ko It seems not only everything is copied but also entire code is reexecuted. That's so bad I actually have no words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

As [the documentation says](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processforkmodulepath-args-options):

> Unlike the [`fork(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) POSIX system call, `child_process.fork()` does not clone the current process.

Answer (score 2):

NodeJS's fork **do** call *nix's fork via [uv_spawn](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/process.html#c.uv_spawn) function from [libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/index.html) library.

Here's how NodeJS forking the process occurs:

1. Your javascript file call [fork function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/76abcf3b870aa7413d643a463517b90fbd676ccf/lib/child_process.js#L114) from child_process.js inside nodejs
2. That fork function validate parameters from your script. If valid, it calls [spawn function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/76abcf3b870aa7413d643a463517b90fbd676ccf/lib/child_process.js#L690)
3. The spawn function creates [ChildProcess](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/76abcf3b870aa7413d643a463517b90fbd676ccf/lib/internal/child_process.js#L251) class as process wrapper for child process
4. Behind the scene, ChildProcess class [bind](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/76abcf3b870aa7413d643a463517b90fbd676ccf/lib/internal/child_process.js#L44) itself with [Process](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v17.x/src/process_wrap.cc) class from native part of NodeJS
5. Spawn function from javascript part calls [spawn function from Process class](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/76abcf3b870aa7413d643a463517b90fbd676ccf/src/process_wrap.cc#L142)
6. Spawn function at Process class then [calls uv_spawn](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/76abcf3b870aa7413d643a463517b90fbd676ccf/src/process_wrap.cc#L262) from `libuv` library
7. If you run NodeJS on *nix system, then `libuv` [utilizes fork function](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/2fbfa0358b3bb920ddd1c2747d4887b35b9ac161/src/unix/process.c#L442)

In short: Yes, **it does copy-on-write** on some *nix machines especially Linux-based.

Despite has potential for saving RAM usage, it's rather CPU-intensive due to complexity of [V8 engine](https://v8.dev/) inside NodeJS, and the NodeJS itself.

> If it does then what do Node.js processes share exactly?

On Linux-based, those processes share unmodified part of memory since being forked. Most of UNIX-based do the same. However on Windows PC, CoW feature still [in research](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2019/04/fork-hotos19.pdf) as 2019.

Comment: Good work following that thread but unfortunately you ended at the wrong conclusion. After forking, the forked process (in the `uv__process_child_init` function) calls `exec`, which discards all memory pages and overwrites the current process with a new one. So, no COW is happening. As the documentation says, the Node.js `fork` is very different from the POSIX `fork`.